# Grails action redirect call

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I'm new to grails and would just like to learn one at a time.

How can I call an action from another action in the same controller:

```
class ListProjectsController {
    def index () {      
        redriect(action: sampleMethod)
    }

    def sampleMethod () {
        //some codes here
    }
}
```

I tried redirect but this caused some error, help please?

here is a picture of the error message

http://i24.photobucket.com/albums/c22/Klifford_Kho/Capture_zps5j8nov9f.png

Comment: What is the error you're getting and what is it you're trying to achieve? Just a redirect to another action when you are at the index?

Comment: yes I only want to learn howto redirect to another action not just from index but any method

Comment: Can you update your question with the error message you're getting. I suspect you don't have a view for the sampleMethod action.

Comment: Already updated it. I still cant upload direct picture here so I provided a link

Comment: It should be `redirect(action: 'sampleMethod')` ... Notice that the name of the method is a `String`.

Comment: just for @kliffordkho info they are called action not method as they are used to render response or redirect to some other action, hence updated in Question

Comment: Ohh okay thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the old style from before Grails 2 when actions were closures. You could quote the name or refer to the closure directly by name. When using methods you can't refer to them as objects, so you just have to quote the name:

```
redirect(action: 'sampleMethod')
```

Answer (score 1):

run grails clean command and update code to

```
redirect(action: 'sampleMethod')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the method name `redirect` as `redriect`.

Comment: Wow stupid mistake.. It still gives same error though after I fix it :((

Comment: same error :No such property: sampleMethod for class: projecttracker.ListProjectsController

Comment: In error you will find **No such property: sampleMethod** because you defined it as sampleMethod instead define it as string like this redirect(action:'sampleMethod')